# services in CentOS e.g. nginx, php-fpm doesn't include symbolic link configuration files

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm, systemctl

I have 2 services in CentOS 7
- nginx
- php-fpm

Those services have main configuration to include *.conf in certain directory.

However, it didn't read the symbolic link file in that certain directory.

Please see screenshot for better clarification.

[image]

When i tried hard copy file to that certain directory, it's working.

Do you have any idea? is it because of centOS issue? Any configuration?
The docs in php-fpm configuration saying that...

```
; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
```

I'm not sure what does it mean by glob(3).

Please advise,

Comment: Please don't post text as screenshots

Comment: You could have another access rights for your `conf` file. Sould you share `ls -la <your .conf file>`?